# Creating instances of public inner classes of generic classes

Tags: java, generics, instantiation, inner-classes

So I have something like the following:

```
public class Enclosing<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // non-relevant code snipped
    public class Inner {
        private T value;
        public Inner(T t) {
            value = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and the world is happy. However, whenever I try to create an instance of `Enclosing.Inner` as follows, I can't:

```
new Enclosing<Integer>.Inner(5);
```

The following error happens:

> Cannot allocate the member type `Enclosing<Integer>.Inner` using a parameterized compound name; use its simple name and an enclosing instance of type `Enclosing<Integer>`.

It is important to note that I cannot make the inner class `static`, because it contains a field of type `T`.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Re: "It is important to note that I cannot make the inner class `static`, because it contains a field of type `T`": That sounds more like a reason to make the inner class generic, using the same bounds as the outer class, than like a reason to make the inner class non-static. (Not to say your inner class *should* be static, though. That depends on your design as a whole, not this one detail.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[To instantiate an inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
  Enclosing<Integer> outerObject = new Enclosing<Integer>();
  Enclosing<Integer>.Inner innerObject = outerObject.new Inner();
```

The ugly syntax suggests a code smell in this design. There should probably be a factory method of some kind in the Enclosing class (`getInner` or something) and the inner class should probably implement a public interface if it is being used from outside its enclosing class.

Comment: The design does indeed stink, and thankfully this isn't production code.

Answer (score 0):

just ran into the same problem, solved it the following way in java7

```
public class Test {
    static class A<T> {
        public class B {

        }
    }
    A<String> a = new A();
    class C extends A.B {
        C() {
            Test.this.a.super();
        }
    }
    public void test() {
        C c = new C();
        A.B b = this.a.new B();
    }
}
```