# What are rules governing instantiating instances of generic outer class and its inner generic inner class and declaring respective references?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

1) Why obj4, obj6, obj7 give compile error, and obj5 is fine?   Where can I read about rules, regulating using such generic coupled outer-inner classes?  I found nothing directly to the point.

When I don't supply any type argument for Inner class in obj3 it is fine (while Inner class needs to be given something for  for its fld3 field of type S), but when I do the same and do not supply type  for Outer class - it does not compile (obj4) - though Object  could be implied...

2) Besides, why obj10 compiles fine, but obj11 fails?   In obj10 line I also write outerInstance.new Inner<>(), implying for Inner  that S is Object. But this is not problem for inner, but same "trick" is problem for Outer...

```
        //in Class A of package com.sth
        public class MyGen<T> {
            T fld1;

            class GenInner<S> {
                T fld2;
                S fld3;
            }

                // within main of Class Driver of same package com.sth
                MyGen.GenInner obj1 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner<Integer>();
                MyGen.GenInner obj2 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner<>();
                MyGen.GenInner obj3 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner();
                //MyGen.GenInner obj4 = new MyGen().new GenInner<String>();  //ERR !
                MyGen.GenInner obj5 = new MyGen<>().new GenInner<String>();

                //MyGen<String>.GenInner obj6;  // ERR
                //MyGen.GenInner<String> obj7;  // ERR
                MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer> obj8;
                MyGen.GenInner obj9;     


  MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer> obj10 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner<>();

  //Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyGen<Object>.GenInner<Integer> to MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer>
  //MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer> obj11 = new MyGen<>().new GenInner<Integer>();  // ERR!
```

These answers relate to my question, but do not provide any clue:

1. [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653444/java-issue-combining-generics-inner-class-and-implements)
2. [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221088/creating-instances-of-public-inner-classes-of-generic-classes)
3. [Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404331/java-generic-class-inner-class-using-parameter-of-outer-class)
4. [Answer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402869/java-generics-with-inner-class-and-inner-interface)
5. [Answer 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716947/instantiating-generic-class-and-implementing-generic-interface)

Comment: Java 8 rejects `obj3` as well: "improperly formed type, some parameters are missing".

Comment: strange, but my Eclipse compiler for Java SE8 compiles obj3 line fine, and no problem in Runtime!  P.S.: MyGen.GenInner obj3 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner();

Comment: I suppose I should be more specific: the compiler of OpenJDK 8 rejects the class instantiation expression assigned to `obj3`.  OpenJDK is also the basis of the Oracle-branded JDK, so this has a lot of weight.  I am not positive that it is right to reject it, @Radiodef's excellent answer notwithstanding, but I am positive that it's unwise to write code like that.  With few exceptions, new code should not use raw types (nor attempt to use rare ones).

Comment: Appreciate pointing this! Seems like Oracle javac (the one OpenJDK uses, I believe) is more attentive to not normal constructions in code :).  I was surprised Eclipse didn't complain about this line of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples which don't compile are mostly examples of *rare types*. (Also, as noted by John in the comments, the `obj3` example shouldn't compile either.)

A [*raw* type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) is the type which is formed by using a generic type without an accompanying type argument list (like e.g. `Set`, as opposed to e.g. `Set<Float>`). A *rare* type is when you have a generic outer class and generic inner class, one of which is raw and the other is not.

Taken from [JLS 4.8 *Raw Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
> - An array type whose element type is a raw type.
> - **A non-`static` member type of a raw type `R` that is not inherited from a superclass or superinterface of `R`.**

(Note that the point in bold implies that if you have a raw type `MyGen`, then its non-`static` member class `GenInner` must also be raw, so there is no such thing as e.g. a `MyGen.GenInner<String>`.)

> Another implication of the rules above is that a generic inner class of a raw type can itself only be used as a raw type:
>
> ```
> class Outer<T>{
>     class Inner<S> {
>         S s;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It is not possible to access `Inner` as a partially raw type (a "rare" type):
>
> ```
> Outer.Inner<Double> x = null;  // illegal
> Double d = x.s;
> ```
>
> because `Outer` itself is raw, hence so are all its inner classes including `Inner`, and so it is not possible to pass any type arguments to Inner.

> **It is a compile-time error to pass type arguments to a non-`static` type member of a raw type that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces.**
>
> **It is a compile-time error to attempt to use a type member of a parameterized type as a raw type.**
>
> This means that the ban on "rare" types extends to the case where the qualifying type is parameterized, but we attempt to use the inner class as a raw type:
>
> ```
> Outer<Integer>.Inner x = null; // illegal
> ```
>
> This is the opposite of the case discussed above. There is no practical justification for this half-baked type. In legacy code, no type arguments are used. In non-legacy code, we should use the generic types correctly and pass all the required type arguments.

The example with `obj11 = new MyGen<>().new GenInner<Integer>()` isn't a rare type. It just looks like a regular failure of type inference with the diamond, because the expression `new MyGen<>()` isn't assigned to anything. In absence of an assignment, `Object` is typically assumed. (More technically it would be whatever the upper bound on the type variable is, which is `Object` in this case.)

---

Also, while not directly related to the question at hand, the following are the only two forms which should actually be used in new code:

```
MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer> ok1 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner<Integer>();
MyGen<String>.GenInner<Integer> ok2 = new MyGen<String>().new GenInner<>();
```

All of the others (which compile) use raw types, and raw types are discouraged.